# A field of characteristic zero can be embedded into $\mathbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am working through Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. Exercise 3.8(b) says that $\deg[m]=m^2$ where $[m]$ is the multiplication map of en elliptic curve. Actually 3.8(a) gives this result for the field $\mathbb C$ and the hint of (b) says that if $K$ can be embedded into $\mathbb C$ then the results follows from (a).

> So how can one embed $K$, a field with characteristic $0$ into $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 7):

Not every field of characteristic $0$ can embed in $\mathbb{C}$.  For instance, if $S$ is a set of variables of cardinality greater than that of $\mathbb{C}$, then the field $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ of rational functions in the variables in $S$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ clearly cannot embed in $\mathbb{C}$.  However, it turns out that this cardinality constraint is the only constraint:

> **Theorem**: Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$.  Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $K$ embeds in $\mathbb{C}$.
> 2. The cardinality of $K$ is $\leq2^{\aleph_0}$.
> 3. The transcendence degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\leq2^{\aleph_0}$.

*Proof*: It is trivial that (1) implies (2) and (2) implies (3).  So suppose the transcendence degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$; let $S\subset K$ and $T\subset \mathbb{C}$ be transcendence bases over $\mathbb{Q}$.  By hypothesis, there exists an injection $S\to T$, which extends uniquely to an embedding of fields $\mathbb{Q}(S)\to \mathbb{Q}(T)\subset\mathbb{C}$.  Since $K$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ and $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, this embedding extends to an embedding $K\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So you assume C has cardinality larger than $\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ right? How can I see this? Maybe any irrational number plus $i$ is transcendent over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @qwwwqq: You can prove that $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality, namely $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @qwwwqq: I assume by "cardinality" you mean "transcendence degree".  Indeed, this is true.  More generally, if $F$ is any field and $L$ is algebraic over $F$, then $|L|\leq |F|\cdot \aleph_0$.  To prove this, note that there are only $|F|\cdot\aleph_0$ different polynomials with coefficients in $F$, each of which can only have finitely many roots in $L$.  Applying this to $L=\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}(T)$ for any transcendence basis $T$ gives that $|F|=2^{\aleph_0}$, and hence $|T|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can construct an explicit set of $2^{\aleph_0}$ algebraically independent elements of $\mathbb{C}$.  See [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/23206/75) on MathOverflow, for instance.