# Isomorphic Modules of Finite dimension over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $K$ be a field, assume $A,B$ are $M_n(K)$ modules with $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}A=\dim_{\mathbb{C}}B<\infty$. I am supposed to show that $A=B$ and that $n$ divides $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}A$.

If I had that $\dim_KA=\dim_KB$ I can easily settle it since $M_n(K)$ is simple and thus it has a unique simple module $U$. Then $A\simeq U^a$ and $B\simeq U^b$ and $a=b$ by dimension comparison. Is there any way to show this or is it a typo perhaps?

Comment: How is $\mathbb C$ related to $K$?

Comment: @JCAA You mean it can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: That is not necessarily true. Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464736/a-field-of-characteristic-zero-can-be-embedded-into-mathbb-c) for details. What I interpret that comment to mean is, “Why do you have both $K$ and $\mathbb C$ in the problem statement?”

Comment: @Carlo I am not sure myself this is why I asked, it is the exact phrasing of the question